# How to stop white "flash" between javascript video re-loads?

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

I am building a site with a video background. I have some javascript (shown below) which selects the most appropriate video source based on screen size and bandwidth. It starts by showing a default low-res version and then as soon as the bandwidth has been calculated, the highest quality that is appropriate is set as the new element source. However, this means that when the resolution is "upgraded" on the `video.load();` command, the background flashes white. Is there a way of getting a less obtrusive transition, something like the video streaming sites changing resolution mid video.

```
<div class="video-container">
  <video autoplay loop mob-hide id="video">
    <source src="Images/Medium.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag. I suggest you upgrade your browser.</video>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
if (screen.width > 992 && screen.width <= 1200) {
            console.log(screen.width);
            if (speedMbps > 0 && speedMbps <= 5) {
                video.setAttribute("src", "Images/Medium.mp4");
            }
            if (speedMbps > 5 && speedMbps <= 10) {
                video.setAttribute("src", "../Images/Large.mp4");
            }
            //more options etc.
        }
video.load();
```

Comment: There really isn't a way to ignore this. You could add a still image as a div behind the video and set it to a z-index. 

-or-

Look into creating a preloader for your website.

Comment: This is essentially happening because the source is being changed from the video, one thing I can think of right now would be to have this initial video on the background of the newer video to be loaded and once this new one starts playing you get rid of the 'background video'? Probably not the best solution but could potentially fix this issue for you.

Comment: @dbrree Thanks. My background color is set to black, so whilst waiting for the first video to load I have a black background, so why is the flash not black? Could your reference to z-index help?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it would resolve the issue or not, but it would be something I personally would try if in your shoes. I may not have the knowledge to solve the issue. Best of luck!